# Spree translate properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, spree

I have property "brand" for products. In my language it is "Značka". I changed presentation's name of this property to my language, but I have "BRANDS" in filter on products page(see on image). Where can I translate this?

[image: http://localhost:3000/t/brands/ruby-on-rails]

Answer (score 0):

This is located within the `spree_taxons` table. You will need to change it there.